# How can I determine whether a QualType contains pointer type in Clang?

Tags: pointers, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I'm diving in clang now.

And I face this problem:

**How can I get to know whether a given QualType type contains pointer type or not?**

Certainly, to deal with simple types, we can use `type->isPointerType()` to determine whether itself is a pointer.

But what about struct, union and class? What about if it has template parameters?

This puzzles me. What I can think about is to write a recursive funcition. But there's quite a great amount of types in clang. I doubt whether I can consider all the situations thoroughly right in this way...

Answer (score 0):

I found this github issue to solve this problem for me.
See if you can cast to a `ConstantArrayType` using `dyn_cast_or_null`

```cpp
QualType t;
const clang::Type* t_ptr = t.getTypePtr();
if( auto t_arrayType =  dyn_cast_or_null<ConstantArrayType>(t_ptr) ){
    std::cout << "is of pointer array type\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "is not of pointer type\n";
}
```

[How to check if a variable declaration in Clang ASTvisitor is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516855/how-to-check-if-a-variable-declaration-in-clang-astvisitor-is-an-array)